# Nextjs dynamic route being catched by index page

Tags: next.js

I have a next app deployed in aws. I'm having an issue with dynamic nested routes, the issue is that given a route eg. /contacts/[contactId].

On my local env if I go to that route, the page renders correctly, if I refresh it it renders correctly as well.

Now on the server it behaves differently, since going to that route while navigating the site will work as intended but if I refresh the page or try to access it by pasting the url in the browser, the one that will catch the route is the index file inside my pages directory, not the nested route.

Has anyone faced this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you deploying the Next.js app to AWS? Are you exporting it as static HTML (`next build && next export`), or do you have it running with `next build && next start`?

Comment: @juliomalves next build && next start.

Comment: And the issue does not happen when running `next build && next start` locally?

Comment: Correct @juliomalves